# Passing data to app.js when bundling in Laravel using Vite

Tags: laravel, vite

Using Vite to bundle assets in Laravel 9 what is the best method to pass data to scripts  in the app.js (or linked files)? Traditionally I would pass the data from controller to blade view and then place the JS code in a  tag in the footer of each individual blade page. However, this seems to go against the pattern of putting JS in the resources/js folder and bundling them using Vite.

For example Chart.js needs a data array to build a chart:

```
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        }]
    },
    options: {
        ...
    }
});
```

If the data array is built in the controller how do you get output this to the "data" property in app.js. In this case just using vanilla JS.

Comment: by using fetch i guess?

Comment: I'm not familiar with fetch

Answer (score 0):

To pass data from Laravel to your JavaScript code bundled with Vite, you can follow these steps:

**Step 1: Prepare the data in your controller**

In your Laravel controller, you'll prepare the data that you want to pass to your JavaScript code. For example, if you want to pass the data for Chart.js, you can create an associative array with the required values:

```
    // YourController.php

public function index()
{
    $chartData = [
        'labels' => ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        'datasets' => [
            [
                'label' => '# of Votes',
                'data' => [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            ]
        ]
    ];

    return view('your_blade_view', compact('chartData'));
}
```

**Step 2: Render the data in your Blade view**

In your Blade view, you can convert the PHP data to a JSON string using the json_encode function and store it in a data attribute on an HTML element, such as a script tag:

```
<!-- your_blade_view.blade.php -->

<div id="chartData" data-chart-data="{{ json_encode($chartData) }}"></div>
```

**Step 3: Access the data in app.js**

Now, in your app.js file, you can access the data using vanilla JavaScript and then pass it to Chart.js:

```
// app.js

import Chart from 'chart.js';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const chartDataElement = document.getElementById('chartData');
    if (chartDataElement) {
        const chartData = JSON.parse(chartDataElement.getAttribute('data-chart-data'));
        const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: chartData,
            options: {
                // ...
            }
        });
    }
});
```

This code will wait for the DOM to be fully loaded, then it will retrieve the data from the chartData element and parse it back to a JavaScript object. After that, it will create the Chart.js chart using the provided data.

This approach allows you to keep your JavaScript in the resources/js folder and bundle it with Vite while still passing data from your Laravel controller to your JavaScript code.